# hp elitebook 840 ubuntu random keys not working properly

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard

When pressing either
windows key, or arrow keys or delete key it doesn't register the click but instead lowers screen brightness. The keys for changing screen brightness also don't work.

I checked the keyboard shortcuts and nothing unusual is set.

I tried different kernels, installing different drivers. I have been stuck at this problem for past 14 days.

I am running 5.3 kernel on ubuntu 18

Comment: Does this also happen when running a different OS? You could test this using a distro running off a USB drive

Comment: no it doesn't only on ubuntu.
i'd like to keep new install as a last resort...